# Slow boot, udisks2.service takes most of the time

Tags: 16.04, boot, fstab

So I recently installed ubuntu on one of my SSDs and the boot time is horrendous. So I look around at different threads and I find some people saying to checking "systemd-analyze blame" and well there's definitely an outlier or two there but I have no idea what they do or how to fix them.

```
joel@joel-Ubuntu-desktop:~$ systemd-analyze blame
         31.993s udisks2.service
          8.551s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          1.060s apache2.service
           487ms dev-sdb5.device
           481ms networking.service
           151ms grub-common.service
           140ms apport.service
           139ms irqbalance.service
           128ms ondemand.service
           128ms speech-dispatcher.service
           126ms lightdm.service
            86ms upower.service
            77ms apparmor.service
            77ms console-setup.service
            75ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            75ms snapd.service
            57ms NetworkManager.service
            48ms keyboard-setup.service
            48ms ModemManager.service
            48ms accounts-daemon.service
            41ms thermald.service
            35ms systemd-journald.service
            31ms systemd-logind.service
```

I also saw some people saying that you should check if the UUID is right in /etc/fstab and it seems to be?

```
joel@joel-Ubuntu-desktop:~$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for joel: 
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="2d3c29cb" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="B4FC7F32FC7EEE4C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2d3c29cb-01"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="7C86D81486D7CCB0" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2d3c29cb-02"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="DCDCC50EDCC4E43C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="2d3c29cb-03"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="82EE6006EE5FF141" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="3fdc4bd6-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="A49CE3C79CE391DA" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="3fdc4bd6-02"
/dev/sda3: UUID="C22C84AA2C849B55" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="3fdc4bd6-03"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="C45CE2A85CE29508" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="3fdc4be3-01"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="74095110-6341-40ba-9a93-3166556e8791" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3fdc4be3-05"
/dev/sdb6: UUID="543386ff-b0bd-429f-a54c-cbc3c59a59a4" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="3fdc4be3-06"
```

After opening /etc/fstab this is what I see:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb5 during installation
UUID=74095110-6341-40ba-9a93-3166556e8791 /               ext4    errors=remoun$
# swap was on /dev/sdb6 during installation
UUID=543386ff-b0bd-429f-a54c-cbc3c59a59a4 none            swap    sw           $
```

Now that's about all the info I've been able to scrounge together, so if anyone knows what the problem/solution might be I would be happy to know! Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at `/var/log/syslog`? E.g., do `grep udisks2 /var/log/syslog` to look for error messages.

Comment: Did  that just now and this is what I found: 

`Dec  7 18:29:35 joel-Ubuntu-desktop org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[1328]: (process:1765): GVFS-RemoteVolumeMonitorDaemon-WARNING **: monitor says it's not supported`